# Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions' was not found . Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, eslint, tsx

I am trying to build a react application. It is using the .tsx format. When trying to build, getting the below error. Tried many fixes and it wont working.

**Failed to compile.

./src/index.tsx

Line 1:1:  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions' was not found  @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions

Line 1:1:  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions' was not found       @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Need more details like your .eslintrc config and eslint packages installed & their versions.

Comment: Have you installed @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser packages.

Comment: I have installed all npm packages from a registery

Comment: not able to add the config file since it exceeds the char limit

Comment: You need to add it as a code block, use the markdown features in the text editor.